# react-native: handling wrong onScroll events inside child FlatList

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-gesture-handler

I found one issue and can someone help me.

I use vertical scroll list(FlatList) and inside it i have also another vertical FlatList.

Inside child FlatList I use onScroll events for customise scroll animation.

issue: when I scroll parent FlatList I get onScroll events inside child and animation glitching.

How can I stop get wrong onScroll event inside child FlatList.

Also I do not use onScroll events inside parent component.

```
<Flatlist
onScroll={
  Animated.event([{nativeEvent: {contentOffset: {y: scrollY}}}], {
  useNativeDriver: false,
  })
}
...
/>
```